# Accessing office component from iis giving com error, windows 7

Tags: com, office-interop

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

i am getting this error when trying to access the Word Application from IIS,
but not getting any exception when running from Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the user IIS is running under don't have the rights to read that registry key.

Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961227/net-efficient-way-to-generate-word-doc-server-side/2961330#2961330) thread (AFAIK office is not intended to be called from server side code)

Best

Adriano