# Download HTML page as .docx with Classic ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic, ms-word, docx

I'm creating an HTML page that can be downloaded as .docx after user click Download button. I've managed to download .docx file but when I try to open it, a popup came out saying "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened".

Fyi, I have tried using these:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
```

How do I get every data (image and table) from HTML page into ms word with extension docx by using Classic ASP?

```
<%if Request("btn_download")<>"" Then 
'Only set the headers if this is request for download
    Response.Buffer = TRUE
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
    Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment; filename=thefile.docx;"
end if
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<%response.write("<h1><center>Welcome!</h1>")%>
<center><img src="http://www.themelab.com/wp-content/uploads/smiley.jpg" alt="Smiley" style="width:auto;height:auto;"></center>

<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<%if Request("btn_download")="" Then 
'Show the download button only if the button has not been clicked.
%>
<p>Click the button below to copy the page as word document.</p>
<form>
<input type="submit" name="btn_download" value="Download">
</form>
<%End If%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't just give it a bunch of HTML and, on download request, set the header to download a file with an extension called docx. Nowhere in your code as you actually generating the document, so it coming in as a blank is of no surprise here. Have you even google'd the DOCX format and how to generate it dynamically? Or did you just think to "wing it it will work of course"?

Comment: you could give a bunch of html and open it as docx. but only with MS word. because MS word tries to "render" the html asa a word doc.

Comment: so what you could try is write the html Code in a variable on the Server and then send the Contents of that variable to the Client with the Header Infos at the end of the page. or save the html in a file on the Server that Ends with "docx" then send the file to the browser. when the Client has MS word installed it will look like a word doc although it is jus a text file with html in it

Comment: Presumably the server you are on can also run asp.net. I would be tempted to call a .net script and use xslt etc to generate the docx file. Not a straight forward task though.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961227/net-efficient-way-to-generate-word-doc-server-side

Alternatively it may be easier to create a RTF file which Ms Word would still open.

Some possible solutions here although I haven't personally tried any:

http://classic-asp-create-rtf.downloads.scripts.filehungry.com/

Comment: @zerohero I get to know the reason it appeared as blank page because of 'Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", content - 1'. So I have deleted the line but what happen is docx can't be opened because of the file is corrupted. When I used doc instead of docx, the file can be opened and saved as .doc, but i want it to be .docx. And of course, I've google'd first before asking here. Instead of saying those things, why not you tell me how to do?

Comment: @ulluoink okay, I will try. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Amos oh I was asked to use classic asp only. But I will look through on what you've suggested. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could link your download button to an ajax script that will call the .net script. This could then return the url of the converted file to the ajax script and then you can throw that into a window for downloading. This will keep the .net script invisible from the view of the average user.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm agree with @Amos, it's much easier to understand. 
Not sure on the exact syntax, but here are some links that you can refer.

1. Export ASP.NET to MSWORD - http://forums.asp.net/t/1204503.aspx
2. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-Word-Excel-PDF-CSV-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx

And also try to learn from this code, it works.

```
<%
    Response.ContentType = "application/msword"    
%>

<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">

...

<v:shape id="_x0000_s1030" type="#_x0000_t75" style='position:absolute;
 left:0;text-align:left;margin-left:0;margin-top:17.95pt;width:7in;height:116.85pt;
 z-index:2;mso-position-horizontal:center;mso-position-horizontal-relative:page;
 mso-position-vertical-relative:page'>
 <v:imagedata src="http://xxx/image001.gif"/>
 <w:wrap anchorx="page" anchory="page"/>
 <w:anchorlock/>

</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><span style='mso-ignore:vglayout;position:
absolute;z-index:0;left:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:24px;width:672px;
height:156px'><img width=672 height=156
src="http://xxx/image001.gif" v:shapes="_x0000_s1030"></span><![endif]>
```